# HTML Table: How to resize data cells when already specified "colspan"?

Tags: html, html-table, width

I have tabular data to display, which has a meaning to both rows and columns.  Columns are time blocks, rows are days. A particular datacell is confined to a single day, but can be in multiple time block. To show this, I am using the colspan tag.

```
<div id = "GuideTable">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan = 3>
    </td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Or Whatever.

I'm trying to apply CSS formating to the entire table, and for changing colors, etc, things are fine, but wanting to have a consistent width is where I am running into problems.

Right now, each data cell's width seems tied to the maximum width in its column (everything auto lines up).  Some columns are itty bitty, others are huge. I'm trying to make columns consistently sized (even if that means every column is as big as the biggest column needs to be), but setting an individual datacells width (either via css or in the tag itself) is getting me nowhere.

I'm thinking maybe the colspan tag is overriding my manual width? If that's the case, how can I change the width of a column as a whole, especially since they aren't explicitly defined? (CAN you explicitly define columns?)

Examples of the CSS I'm using:

```
#GuideTable td{
background:#ffffff;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could give an example that would be great.

Table's have many special properties, cells must always fill up to 100% of the width of the table - period.

If you give a width property to a cell, that will work. CSS gets iffy as many things won't work.

Comment: Problem is that my example is generated by Ruby on Rails (which adds even more complications) and is about 20,000 lines long (it's a HUGE, table). I think my main issue is that because of how huge the table is, and how the width of the table is something I can't specify (because I don't get to know in advance how big the table needs to be), some weird automation was probably going on, making the table just big enough to barely fit all the content, but resulted in random column widths.

Comment: Then set a standard for the column widths and see how it looks, then adjust accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

So I ran a little experiment using the following code

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    td
    {
        width: 100px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">First Row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Second</td>
            <td colspan="2">Row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>The</td>
            <td>Third</td>
            <td>Row</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And The resulting table had a total width of 300px (give or take).  and each cell was 100px wide.  Perhaps there's something else that's affecting your cell widths.  Try stripping away the CSS and adding it back part by part, even rediculious stuff can totally mess up CSS (like font-family causing a table to fly way off to the left, as I'm dealing with at the moment)

Comment: Thanks for the advice...I did try stripping off the css, and modifying the total width of the table...nothing really changed, though. It was super frustrating. I DID find I could change the height, normally, though.

In the end, what I did was a hack, and added a 1 pixel square image, stretched to a width that worked for me. It works, and gives me less headaches, but it's probalby not the "correct" solution. (But I needed one quick).

Answer (score 0):

*(Just found this while searching for something else)*

If you don't need to support IE6 you can use the attribute selector to reset widths to cells with `colspan`:

```
td { width: 100px; }
td[colspan] { width: auto; }
```

If you do have to support IE6 you'll need to add a class to each cell with colspan:

```
<td colspan="2" class="colspan">...</td>
```

and

```
td { width: 100px; }
td.colspan { width: auto; }
```